# ¿Es correcta esta transformación de class component a function en react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, funciones, class, usestate

como hobby estoy aprendiendo muy de a poco react.js, estoy haciendo un proyecto de un hotel de youtube ([proyecto hotel react.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXJOvkVYQqA&t)) el cual tiene varios años de publicado y está hecho con class component, como en el curso que hice el profesor comentó que eso está quedando obsoleto y lo mejor es usar functions, hice la transformación de class component a function. Funciona correctamente y queria que me digan si la sintaxis es correcta, porque que funcione no significa que esté totalmente bien hecho :D

class component, hecho tal cual el video:

```js
export default class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };
  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nav-center">
          <div className="nav-header">
            <Link to="/">
              <img src={logo} alt="Beach Resort" />
            </Link>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="nav-btn"
              onClick={this.handleToggle}
            >
              <FaAlignRight className="nav-icon" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul
            className={this.state.isOpen ? "nav-links show-nav" : "nav-links"}
          >
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/rooms">Rooms</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Como quedó el código anterior pero sin class component:

```js
export default function Navbar() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setState(!state);
  };

    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="nav-center">
          <div className="nav-header">
            <Link to="/">
              <img src={logo} alt="Beach Resort" />
            </Link>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="nav-btn"
              onClick={handleToggle}
            >
              <FaAlignRight className="nav-icon" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul
            className={state ? "nav-links show-nav" : "nav-links"}
          >
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/rooms">Rooms</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
}
```

Comment: lo unico diferente que haria es usar la sintaxis por defecto para componentes: const MiComponente = () => { ...... return () } y luego export default MiComponente. Si usas vs code ponle las extensiones  simple react snippets y react/redux/native snippets y por ejemplo con poner rafce ya te sale el componente armado con el nombre del archivo como nombre de funcion y todo

Comment: @HernánGarcia ¿Dónde puede consultarse eso de **la sintaxis por defecto para componentes**?